# What is this button-up shirts attire that is usually seen in fighting anime and martial arts movies?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, culture

What do they call those button-up shirts you often see in fighting anime and martial arts movies, like *Dragon Ball* series?

[image]

Comment: Probably this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangzhuang but I don't know much about this, so I'll let someone else write an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of suits, popularized by Bruce Lee and Ip Man.

The depicted "Tangzhuang" or "Tang suit".

[image: tang suit]

and the longer robe-like "Changshan'.

[image: chanshan]

Toriyama mentioned that he admired Bruce Lee, and the film *Enter The Dragon* had a profound impact on the *Dragonball* series.

Trivia: During the Song, Yuan, and Ming dynasties, all things related to China were referred to as "Tang", both as a proxy for the country and it's people. Chinatowns are referred to as "Tangren Jie" (唐人街, Tang People Street). Despite the costume being from the Qing dynasty and derived from the Manchurian horses jacket "magua", it evolved to be one a symbol of the Han people and Chinese diaspora oversea, being known as the aforementioned "Tang suit".